# How can I start X server ons boot?

Tags: redhat, rhel6, x11

In most case I login to the server as a root and start the X server manually by calling the `startx` function. After the I can use X11 forwarding. However I would like to know how can I start X11 as a service on boot time?

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default runlevel in `/etc/inittab`.

Runlevel 3, which is most probabyl set right now only starts multiuser without graphical systems.

If you change it to 5 it should start X11 on boot.

Comment: if the 3 in the `id:3:initdefault:` is changed, than the it will start the xserver on boot?

Comment: As long as a display manager is installed it should, yes.